# SharePoint 2016: how to force JS to execute on every site page despite Ajax and/or MDS?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-2016

I'm implemeting a very simple use case, and yet not only do I not find a solution, but I can't find any article that talks about it, as if I was the only one.

**I want my custom Javascript to execute on every page** of a given SharePoint site.

Easy, you'll say. Well, no. Far from it, like always with SharePoint.

> Steps to reproduce :
>
> - Create a out-of-the-box publishing site
> - Include the custom javascript below using any of the means I describe below
> - Go to the site, to the home page. It's a publishing site, so by default you should have the left navigation pane with at least "**Home**" and "**Documents**" by default.
> - The first time you load the page, the javascript executes.  Now, click on "documents". The page changes but the Javascript is *not* executed.

That's because SharePoint uses **Ajax**. Even if the **MDS** is disabled. It uses Ajax through the hash ( # ) in the URL.

For example, it transforms a very inocuous link like this one :

> < a href src="/SitePages/Home.aspx">

into this URL when you click it:

> https://your-url/sites/your-site/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/Home.aspx

Here is my Javascript :

```
if (ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded && _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames) {
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push(ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(
        function () {
            alert("It's working!");
        }, "sp.js"));
}
```

So, I've tried the following ways of including the Javascript :

1. **Through a User Custom Action.** I've used [this very handy page](http://johnliu.net/blog/2015/12/the-safest-future-proof-way-to-brand-your-sharepoint-and-sharepoint-online) to add it, but that's not relevant. The action is added to the site and I can see the JS in the DOM on first load. But then after I click on a link in the page and after SP uses Ajax, it does not execute it again.
2. **By modifying the master page** -- namely: **seattle.html**. at first I included it this way, simply under other native inclusions :

> <head runat="server">
>
> ...
>
> <!--SPM:<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="suitelinks.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false"/>-->
>
> <!--SPM:<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" Name="~sitecollection/SiteAssets/MYJAVASCRIPT.js" runat="server"/>-->

But then I read about **AjaxDelta** (here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/dn456543.aspx ) , and I moved my inclusion (still in the header) into < AjaxDelta >, like this :

> <head runat="server">
>
> ...
>
> <!--SPM:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" Container="false" runat="server">-->
>
> <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server"/>-->
>
> <!--SPM:<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="AdditionalPageHead" AllowMultipleControls="true"/>-->
>
> <!--SPM:<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" Name="~sitecollection/SiteAssets/MYJAVASCRIPT.js" runat="server"/>-->
>
> <!--SPM:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->

...and yet nothing works. The Javascript is never executed when  switching between pages of the same site by clicking on SharePoint's "managed" links.

I'm looking for a solution that handles elegantly SharePoint's Ajax, not something heavy and risky that hijacks every hyperlink on a page. For example I've tried to hook my code onto **ajaxNavigate** methods (for example : **addNavigate**) but I'm not sure I understand what's actualy going on there and if it could be of any help to me.

**EDIT :**

- There seems to be a consensus (for example, [here](https://chuvash.eu/2016/04/27/minimal-download-strategy-simple/) at the very bottom) that **User Custom Actions** get executed no matter what -- because SharePoint allegedly places their ScriptLink into the AjaxDelta for some reason. Well, that's not what I witnessed.
- There's another consensus that this issue can be adressed by using "**RegisterModuleInit**". This doesn't work for me either.

I'm extermely puzzled. I think those two solutions do address navigation issues when the user clicks on a link and then clicks "**back**". But it does NOT address SharePoint's clever "managed", Ajax-riddled, hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a solution that never seems to fail so far. That's a real relief.

Short answer: use  **asyncDeltaManager.add_endRequest**

This MSDN discussion suggests a simple way to implement it:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1ae292b4-3589-46f6-bedc-7bd9dc741f1b/javascript-code-to-execute-after-all-the-elements-and-css-are-loaded?forum=appsforsharepoint

```
$(function () {
  ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
      if (typeof asyncDeltaManager != "undefined")
           asyncDeltaManager.add_endRequest(MYCUSTOMCODE); //execute it after any ajax event
      else 
           MYCUSTOMCODE(); //execute it at first load
  }, "start.js");
});
```

This shows how to include it properly in SharePoint's cycle (with ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded ) 
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/171490/javacript-only-executed-on-first-page-load

Full-blown solution (objet "LefeCycleHelper"), by Mx
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/192974/where-to-place-a-js-script-with-whom-i-need-to-get-an-div-id/193009#193009

```
//use an IIFE to create a scope and dont dirty the global scope
(function (_) {

// use strict to ensure we dont code stupid
'use strict';

var initHandlers = [];
var initMDSHandlers = [];

var ensureSharePoint = function (handler) {
    var sodLoaded = typeof (_v_dictSod) !== 'undefined' && _v_dictSod['sp.js'] != null && _v_dictSod['sp.js'].state === Sods.loaded;

    if (sodLoaded) {
        handler();
    } else {
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () { });
        SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(handler, 'sp.js');
    }
};

var initMDS = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < initMDSHandlers.length; i++) {
        initMDSHandlers[i]();
    }
};

var init = function () {
    // Register MDS handler
    if ('undefined' != typeof g_MinimalDownload && g_MinimalDownload && (window.location.pathname.toLowerCase()).endsWith('/_layouts/15/start.aspx') && 'undefined' != typeof asyncDeltaManager) {
        asyncDeltaManager.add_endRequest(initMDS);
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < initHandlers.length; i++) {
            initHandlers[i]();
        }
    }
};

var registerInit = function (handler) {
    initHandlers.push(handler);
};

var registerInitMDS = function (handler) {
    initMDSHandlers.push(handler);
};

var domReady = (function (handler) {
    var fns = [];
    var listener;
    var loaded = (document.documentElement.doScroll ? /^loaded|^c/ : /^loaded|^i|^c/).test(document.readyState);

    if (!loaded) {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', listener = function () {
            document.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', listener);
            loaded = 1;
            while (listener = fns.shift()) listener();
        });
    }

    return function (fn) {
        loaded ? setTimeout(fn, 0) : fns.push(fn);
    };
})();


var attachToLoad = function (functionToAttach) {
    registerInit(functionToAttach);
    registerInitMDS(functionToAttach);
   domReady(function () {
       init();
    });
};

_.AttachToLoad = attachToLoad;

// THIS WILL PROTECT YOUR GLOBAL VAR FROM THE GARBAGE COLLECTOR
window.LifeCycleHelper = _;
if (window.Function != 'undefined' && typeof (Function.registerNamespace) == 'function') {
    Function.registerNamespace('LifeCycleHelper');
}
})({});

var theCodeYouWantToRun = function () {
    alert('theCodeYouWantToRun');
};

window.LifeCycleHelper.AttachToLoad(theCodeYouWantToRun);
```